# VLAN interface and IPv6 SLAAC

Tags: linux, ipv6, vlan

Marvell A38x SDK Buildroot-2015.11 which comes with Busybox-1.24.1.
I need to add VLAN interface and get SLAAC address from this interface.
I could add VLAN interface  with the following commands

```
vconfig add eth1 3004   - vconfig is from busybox
ifconfig eth1.3004  up 
ifconfig -a      - see the outpout of eth1.3004
```

Two Questions:

1. How can  I  generate this VLAN interface eth1.3004 automatically on boot-up ? any advice to modify `/etc/network/interfaces` or `if-pre-up.d` using `ifup`/`ifdown`?
2. Option  makes eth1.2004  aquires IPv6 SLAAC ?
   My SOC board vendor  says the slaac router advertisement is working.
   When I run the command:  `ifconfig eth1.3004  up`,  but still only see link-local IPv6. Any advice to debug this issue ?

```
eth1.3004 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:43:66:35:37
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:43ff:fe66:3537/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:468 (468.0 B)
```